# 2D vector editor with "constraints" support

Tags: vector-graphics, editor

I was so impressed how easy is to draw sketches in [`Solidworks`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SolidWorks), that I now think that all other ways of 2D editing is a slag. On can draw simple 2D primitives and then apply constaints to them: "equal" length, perpendicular, tangent, numeric values etc. This is especially useful, when you made some mistakes in sizes in the beginning. In conventional editors one would redraw everything from scratch, while in `Solidworks` one should only change one number.

Are there any 2D vector editors with such possibility, which are as feature rich, as Adobe Illustrator?

---

I found `SolveSpace`, but it is making unreasonable assumptions:

[image]

Particularly, it assumes existance of some "closed contours" which are more than number of connected lines.

Answer (score 1):

A program called [SolveSpace](http://solvespace.com/index.pl), which also performs 3D editing, will allow you to apply constraints in the manner you describe.

[Fusion 360](https://www.autodesk.com/products/fusion-360/overview) also supports 2D construction, but it is also not limited to 2D and supports 3D modeling.

Not knowing your objection to 3D capability, it's difficult to accurately determine an optimum response. Feature rich is a somewhat ambiguous parameter.

Comment: No need for 3D. Anyway, I need just a geometry with constraints, I don't need any "construction" assumptions.